# parabolic partial differential equations

Tags: math, differential-equations

My application has some parabolic partial differential equations...which are inter-related and use some variables which the user inputs via a UI from a desktop application.
Can you guide me through as to which software or library or a particular language would serve the best purpose for the above?

Comment: Do you want numeric or symbolic solutions ?  (Of course, most PDEs don't have symbolic solutions, but that's another matter.)

Comment: I will be able to answer you but you have first to tell more about your PDEs. Are they linear ? On what domain, how many space variables ? What boundary conditions ? What initial conditions ? What regularity of initial conditions ? What do you expect: accuracy, stability, robustness, speed ? There is no general purpose PDE solver, even for parabolic equations, so you have to provide much more info. Most importantly, you have to specify what you know about (parabolic) PDEs, and how much code you're ready to write.

Comment: Have you tried Modelica Language before? There are also open source implementations OpenModelica and Jmodelica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Python language with:

- [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) for UI
- [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) for scientific computing

Or [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/), or its free counterpart [gnu octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html) or scilab, of freemat.

Or just crank it up in Wolfram Alpha web UI.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X^2%2B2x%2B1%3D0

Or [Wolfram Mathematica 8](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/).

Answer (score 3):

Since you said "equations", I'll assume there's more than one and that they're coupled.  It's highly unlikely that you'll find a closed-form solution for a problem that difficult.

When I hear "parabolic PDE", the prototype for me is transient diffusion.  That usually means a numerical integration forward in time using explicit Euler (small steps, unstable), implicit, or Crank-Nicholson integration scheme.

I'd discretize using finite element methods and weighted residuals.  This is how you turn those PDEs into matrix equations.

Once both of those are decided upon, you'll have a set of linear algebra problems to solve repeatedly for each time step.  You can use any good linear algebra library you have available in the language of your choice.

Maybe MATLAB or [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/about.html), its open source cousin, could help you here.

Comment: How can you give such advice without seeing the equations ? Crank Nicholson may be quite unstable for non smooth initial data. You cannot suggest finite differences if you don't know the domain.

Comment: Actually, for *linear* systems of parabolic PDEs, you're likely to find a "closed form solution" as a convolution with some kernel.

Comment: I didn't suggest finite differences; I said finite elements and weighted residuals.  And I prefaced all my remarks by saying what I thought of when I heard parabolic PDEs that it brought transient heat transfer to mind; I never once implied that I could read someone's mind and know about equations that weren't listed.  And I offered CN OR Euler OR implicit without specifying one.  Where do you get off chiding me about CN?  Nobody said linear or non-linear, so your solution may not apply.  I wish you had the courage to offer an answer so I could bitch you out and downvote you.  No courage.

Comment: "Some kernel" - no one said anything in the original question one way or the other as to whether a suitable Green's function or kernel function existed.  You have no more idea about likelihood of existence than you do about the smoothness of the initial data.

Comment: @duffymo: I swear I read finite differences... Never mind. Recommanding anything even remotely specific without extensive knowledge about the PDE is worth a downvote, for reasons I think you perfectly know. I mentioned in a comment to OP's answer that I'm willing to answer provided he gives extra info (so that you can downvote:) ). For the smooth Green function thing, okay. I'm assuming something linear for instance.

Comment: I'm arguing that I wasn't nearly as specific as you're accusing me of being.  And why is it acceptable for you to make assumptions without additional information but no one else?  Alexandre C, you're obviously quite knowledgeable, but I think in this case your downvote is unjust.  Those should be reserved for answers that are clearly wrong.  Without further information, I think mine provides food for thought and possible direction.  You aren't being fair.

Comment: "...Recommanding anything even remotely specific without extensive knowledge..." - this is utter nonsense.  People weigh in on all kinds of stuff with knowledge that's far from extensive.  If that kind of detail was required for every question there'd be a lot fewer answers here.